# MongoDB Schema for Hotel booking / room availability

Tags: mongodb, schema, nosql

I’m currently building an  application with a similar model to hotel booking sites.

Currently considering ways of handling availability searching.

My model looks something a little bit like the below:

**Hotel**
_id
name
description
star_rating
address
lat
lon

I then thought of having an availability collection something like this:

**Availability**
hotel_id (if availability is it's own collection)
date
room_type
room_max_occupancy
price

date would store a single day the room was available
room_type would be things like “Twin” “Double”
room_max_occupancy would be 2, 3, etc...

An example query would be:
a room in  from 1st-8th June, for 2 people.

For the “search results” I’d need to return hotel.name, hotel.description, hotel.star_rating.

I’m looking for the most efficient way to store this data for the type of query listed above?

Should the availability collection be it’s own collection, or a sub-document of Hotel?

If it’s own collection, should I add the lat lon to the availability (along with hotel_id) to make searching more efficient?

Comment: Most efficient in terms of space (disk / RAM), inserting, or finding free rooms? And shouldn't there be a Room collection (which might contain a list of available / unavailable time spans)?

Comment: Do you care about multiple people searching at the same time, seeing availability and then possibly not being able to book if someone else beat them to it?

Comment: Please note a couple of things (I'm familiar with the domain discussed) : You probably want a finer-grained aggregate than room_id to list availabilities for. i.e: agent-offers often take other things beside room_id into account to link availability to, e.g: breakfast-included, special multiday (2=3 day) offers, etc.   So, although roomId might be sufficient to start out with as a means of aggregating availability on, it doesn't let you model everything potential partners (like booking.com) throw at you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets work backwards, starting from the query. What you would like is a list of available rooms for a range of dates. It is not feasible to store rooms as 'not booked' for future dates, so you'll have a collection for booking information. A query would look like:

```
db.booking.find({date: {$gte: from_date, $lt: to_date}});
```

This will perhaps get us a list of Room IDs.

Collection: `booking` 
Fields: `room_id, date`

The next query is one that gets us a list of Room Ids that fit the constraints. Something like:

```
db.rooms.find({room_type: "Double", room_max_occupancy: 2});
```

Barring the dates for which the rooms have been booked, we can get the availability status. If the average number of rooms per hotel is high, its not worth the space used to potentially replicate of hotel information, instead we should have Hotel Ids for each room. You must then aggregate a unique list of hotels to avoid duplicate queries

Collection: `rooms` Fields: `room_type, room_max_occupancy, price, hotel_id`

The final query is for fetching information on hotels:

```
db.hotels.find({id: <ID>}, {'name': 1, 'description': 1, 'star_rating': 1});
```

Collection: `hotels` Fields: `name, description, star_rating, address, lat, lon`

If you do need to have direct access to availability information, you will have to decide on a date limit upto which you'll allow booking (say 6 months into the future). Everyday, a script must run to add a new day of (blank) availability information to the database. You can modify the booking collection as:

Collection: `booking` Fields: `room_id, date, is_available, hotel_id` (along with fields to hold the particulars of the booking process)

Your query should now have an additional constraint:

```
db.booking.find({is_available: true, date: {$gte: from_date, $lt: to_date}});
```

You'll get access the room IDs and the hotel IDs (some redundancy to skip an additional query), from which you can get the display details for the hotel

Comment: appologies- i think you may of mis-understood the model somewhat? It's along the lines of booking.com and hotwire.com (that kind of thing) - so need to search listed availability... so "It is not feasible to store rooms as 'not booked' for future dates" is pretty much what i think we're going to need to do?

Comment: I see there is a limit on how far in the future you can book rooms. So at the cost of additional space, you can add an `is_available` field to the booking collection. I've modified my answer to reflect this

Comment: sounds like this will require three queries just to see what hotel has available rooms for the time period - that seems very inefficient...

Comment: Its a tradeoff between space and time. You could replicate the hotel info, will take up a lot of space, edits will be hard. With the right indexes, mongo can get back with results fast. Multiple queries shouldn't be an issue

Comment: is it possible to do a map-reduce on a query: for example - get all hotels near xyz,xyz - now mapReduce on only ones that are available?

Comment: What do you want to use map-reduce for? And what do you mean by possible? Possible in real time? Possible as an offline task? You should try and come up with a separate question that focuses on your issue. It'll get more attention

Comment: Well, i was trying to clarify what i wanted since your answer didn't answer this question fully....

Comment: @Alex I would like to suggest that adding 'available dates' out in the future is not a good solution. Use inverse logic. Do a query to get all reservations that match the dates requested, then map reduce those out of the list of all hotels in that region/city, then you're left with a list of hotels/rooms that are available at that time. This way guests can search as far in to the future as they want with no issue. If no properties are returned for a set of dates, then all properties are available. Run a quick availability check right at booking to make sure it hasn't booked since first search.

Comment: Though it was an old question but I happen to have similar requirement. Based on the question and answer, I have one thing that can not understand here. How do you manage the availability counters for each room? For example, on a particular day, there are 10 rooms available on 2016/1/31 in Hotel X, then there shall be up to 10 reservation on that day. The solution seems not able to address this.  By simply querying the booking records, the available counts can be deducted, but as pointed out, it would be not efficient if the query is dominant operation,